# Plot the function which is greater at the current value - pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have two Gaussian plots of the function

```
f(x) = exp(- x^2 / (2 * (0.5)^2))
```

and

```
g(x) = exp(- (x - 2)^2 / (2 * (0.5)^2))
```

[image: plots]

I'm now trying to "add up" those two function to only one plot that follows the green line from -∞ to 1, where it intersects with the red line and from 1 to +∞ it should follow the red line. So that the resulting plot looks a bit like a very curvy letter *M*.

Mathematically this function I want to plot can be described as the following:

```
       | f(x) if f(x) ≥ g(x)
R(x) = |
       | g(x) if g(x) > f(x)
```

How can I put this in a `pgfplots`-plot?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[samples = 100, domain = -2:4] {
            exp(- x^2 / (2 * (0.5)^2))
        };
        \addplot[samples = 100, domain = -2:4] {
            exp(- (x-2)^2 / (2 * (0.5)^2))
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is the "function" ifthenelse, so you may want to plot `ifthenelse(f(x)>g(x),f(x),g(x))`. And please post an MWE.

Comment: Less comprehensive than the given answer, but: Since you know the switch happens at 1, you can use `domain=-2:1` and `domain=1:4`.  But that's less useful if you don't know the intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit confused about `h(x)`. Assuming it is identical to `f(x)`, you could do.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x) = exp(- \x^2 / (2 * (0.5)^2));},
declare function={g(\x) = exp(- (\x - 2)^2 / (2 * (0.5)^2));}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-3:5,samples=100]
        \addplot[red,thick,no marks] {f(x)};
        \addplot[green!50!black,thick,no marks] {g(x)};
        \addplot[blue,thick,no marks] {ifthenelse(f(x)>g(x),f(x),g(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and the missing MWE. `h(x)` should be `f(x)` that was just a typo. Thanks for your idea of the `ifthenelse`, that worked out great!

Answer (score 2):

To simplify your question: You want to do `R(x) = max(f(x),g(x))` which of course you can also do in TikZ and therefore in PGFPlots ...

I extended your example a bit to showcase the advantage of this solution in case you have more than 2 functions.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        /pgf/declare function={
            % declare a "master function" ...
            a(\x,\b) = exp(- (\x + \b)^2 / (2 * (0.5)^2));
            %
            % ... this allows to easily create the other functions
            f(\x) = a(\x,0);
            g(\x) = a(\x,-1);
            h(\x) = a(\x,-2);
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-2:4,
        smooth,
    ]
        \begin{scope}[
            ultra thick,
            no markers,
        ]
            \addplot {f(x)};
            \addplot {g(x)};
            \addplot {h(x)};
        \end{scope}

        \addplot [mark=*,green] {max(f(x),g(x),h(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]